# Correct way to read stream char by char

Tags: c#, stream, tcpclient

I am trying to read a steam, the stream is continues.

I have gotten to the following, but i find it a bit strange that i will constantly have to check for the empty stream character. Are there no way to make the thread sleep until there are more data?

Speed here is very important, as it have to handle a high load.

```
NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
try
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    char c = (char)reader.Read();
    while (true)
    {
        if (c != (char)65535)
        {
            if (c == StreamSettings.MessageSplitChar)
            {
                // Do work with string here
            } 
            else
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No work to do sleep some
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        c = (char)reader.Read();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Well, you don't.  If you get -1 from StreamReader.Read() then there will be no more data to receive.  You might as well use ReadToEnd(), then process the text.  The generally smarter way to transfer text is to first send the number of bytes so the receiver knows when to stop reading.  That's how HTTP works for example.

Comment: The clients on the other end of the stream are generating data. So there might be times in between messages where the search have read to the end of stream, but the client will write more later.
If i read to the end will it never end as the stream will remain open during the lifetime of the client.

Comment: That makes little sense, StreamReader.Read() will simply block instead of returning -1 if that's the case.  The advantage of the HTTP approach is that the socket doesn't have to be closed to indicate the end.

Comment: ReadToEnd() will continue reading untill the stream closes! And closing the stream is what i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Read` waits until at least one more byte is available. You do not need to wait yourself. It returns `-1` at the end of the stream.

`(char)65535` is a hack. This is an overflowing cast. Simply check for `-1`.